# Drag and Drop Row in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have windows form with DataGridView and I need to enable drag  and drop rows in this DataGridView.

It is filled from the database. My code does not work properly because after the first drag and drop I cant drop row to the right position.

This is the `Load` forms where `DataGridView` is filled from database

```
DataTable bsPeople;
Rectangle dragBoxFromMouseDown;
    int rowIndexFromMouseDown;
    int rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop; 
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView1.AllowDrop = true;
        bsPeople= objPeople.ReturnPeople(); // fill data from SQL Server 
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsPeople;
    }
```

This are the Drag and Drop events

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.Button ==MouseButtons.Left)))
        {
            if (((dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty)
                        && !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y)))
            {
                DragDropEffects dropEffect = DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown], DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        rowIndexFromMouseDown = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
        if ((rowIndexFromMouseDown != -1))
        {
            Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2), e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)), dragSize);
        }
        else
        {
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = Rectangle.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point clientPoint = DataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = DataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).RowIndex;
        if ((e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move))
        {
            DataGridViewRow rowToMove = (DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow));
            object[] celldata=new object[DataGridView1.ColumnCount];
            for (int col = 0; (col
                        <= (rowToMove.Cells.Count - 1)); col++)
            {
                celldata[col] = rowToMove.Cells[col].Value;
            }

            DataRow row = bsPeople.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = celldata;
            bsPeople.Rows.InsertAt(row, rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop);
            rowToMove.DataGridView.Rows.Remove(rowToMove);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a MSDN code sample for moving rows up and down via buttons which is not what you are looking for but the base logic can be used that are in several language extension method for vb.net and C#. No need to download, just browse the code. I did not include code here since it uses buttons rather than drag and drop. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Move-rows-updown-and-987fe786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Drag & Drop**

You need to delete and insert the **right** `DataRows`. Try this:

```
private void DGV_DragDropData(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   Point clientPoint = DGV.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
   rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop =
       DGV.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).RowIndex;
   if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
   {
      DataGridViewRow rowToMove = (DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow));
      // find the row to move in the datasource:
      DataRow oldrow = ((DataRowView)rowToMove.DataBoundItem).Row;
      // clone it:
      DataRow newrow = bsPeople.NewRow();
      newrow.ItemArray = oldrow.ItemArray;
      bsPeople.Rows.InsertAt(newrow, rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop);
      bsPeople.Rows.Remove(oldrow);
   }
}
```

Note that the code only moves **one** row. For moving multiple rows there are a few more tricks needed..

**State of the Row:**

Also note that you may need to set the `RowState` of the new row, depending on your needs. As it is added you may want to set it it `Unchanged` by calling `newRow.AcceptChanges()`  or maybe to some other state, depending on the state of the original row.

To modify the `RowState` a few rules apply:

- The `DataRow` **must** reside in a `DataTable`; after you have just created it, the state is `Unattached` and you can't change it.
- Only `Unchanged` rows can be changed by the `SetAdded` or `SetModified` methods; so you must call `AcceptChanges()` first.

This should do the job:

```
   if (oldrow.RowState != DataRowState.Unchanged) newrow.AcceptChanges();
   if (oldrow.RowState == DataRowState.Added) newrow.SetAdded();
   if (oldrow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified) newrow.SetModified();
```

These lines must be added **after** the new row is added to the table..