# C# control Dragging animation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a tableLyoutPanel to hold buttons in its cells . I can move them between cells and swap using Drag and Drop functionality. all what I need is to show the button while dragging and moving with the courser. or just capture an image of it and make it move with mouse drag. can you help me with that in ***C#***? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using windows forms or WPF?

Comment: You may want to study [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825334/drag-and-drop-row-in-a-datagridview/34826867?s=2|64.2081#34826867)..